# Where or how is the Jhtml class defined?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm trying to get started with Joomla extension development, and am having trouble following along with simple examples.

Where is the `Jhtml` class defined and/or documented? I see it being used in examples and extensions that come with Joomla, but I can't find any current documentation on it. Existing links into https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/ all appear to be broken, and my attempts to grep the Joomla source have not turned up anything.

**Update:**

Please tell me whether I understand this correctly. It looks like `libraries/classmap.php` calls `JLoader::registerAlias` to dynamically alias the name `JHtml` to `HTMLHelper`. I'm unable to find documentation on `JHtml` because there is no such class.

Comment: Your update is entirely correct (surprised no one answered this before now). Anytime you're looking for a a class definition, especially for one that starts with "J", start in classmap.php; you'll probably get there faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `JHtml` class was changed to `\Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper` (`/libraries/src/HTML/HTMLHelper.php`) since 3.8 as a part of namespacing the core.

I believe you can still use [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks) (and [API ref](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.HTML.HTMLHelper.html)) of the old `JHTML` class.

The best way to learn everything about it - use IDE like PHPStorm for example, and you'll get a lot of useful hints, not to mention class propositions based on partial name typed.

Also what you may put a file like this one: [_ide_helper.php](https://gist.github.com/alex7r/3a996693f13cb8290cd66a28ab6976a7)
in the root of your project to make your transition from <3.8 smoother with IDE.

Comment: Hey alexandr could add a link to the old documentation to yr post?

Comment: Added, but it's almost safe to say that Joomla has almost no documentation for developers, but PHPDocs of the methods are useful.

Answer (score 6):

As of Joomla 3.8, the majority of classes have been namespaced but with a fallback for when migrating to J4.

So, you can still use `JHtml::XXX`, but the new approach is:

```
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

HTMLHelper::_('script', 'path/to/file.js');
HTMLHelper::_('stylesheet', 'path/to/file.css');
```

---

You can find the source code for the `HTMLHelper` class here:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/src/HTML/HTMLHelper.php

The code is still the same as it was before, so you can continue reading through the current Joomla documentation for `JHtml`.

- https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks
- https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript

Comment: But what does this do specifically?  Does it add the script to the head of the page?  YES IT DOES!

Comment: So we should not use `JFactory::getDocument();` anymore?

Comment: @Eoin, you can still use it if you want, but I'd suggest against it. `HTMLHelper` has additional features such as override support.

Comment: addScriot has versioning but that's not a counterargument. What do you mean by override support?

Comment: Let say you create an extension and load a Javascript file within it using `HTMLHelper`, users will be able to copy/paste the file into their template directory and make modifications to it if they want. Joomla will automatically load the overridden JS file from the template directory if it exists.

Comment: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/src/HTML/HTMLHelper.php#L398

Answer (score 5):

Yeah the google links are messed up because of the namespacing and shifting changes.  Most of the Joomla core classes are all now in libraries/src here:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/staging/libraries/src

JHtml is in the HTML folder. The api listing is here:

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.HTML.HTMLHelper.html

As for "Documentation"... lol.